# Trying to figure out syntax for a connect by

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

So, i've been passed a code, which i'm trying to execute in SQL Developer, but i'm getting a "missing right parentheses" error.

This is the code:

```
(SELECT A.ID_STAGE ID_INT_STAGE
   FROM STAGE_D A, 
   ( SELECT STAGE_LINK_B.ID_STAGE, STAGE_LINK_B.ID_PRIOR_STAGE 
     FROM STAGE_LINK_B
     CONNECT BY PRIOR STAGE_LINK_B.ID_STAGE = STAGE_LINK_B.ID_PRIOR_STAGE
     START WITH STAGE_LINK_B.ID_STAGE = V$[STAGE_D.ID_STAGE]
   )B
 WHERE A.ID_STAGE = B.ID_PRIOR_STAGE
 AND A.CD_STAGE = 'INT'
) STG
WHERE INT_F.ID_INT_STAGE = STG.ID_INT_STAGE
AND INT_F.IND_CURR_ROW = 'Y';
```

I've been trying to read up on connect prior, but it seems like the error is in the syntax.

Any help appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Your parentheses just aren't right. This query that you've been passed won't work even if you remove `CONNECT BY`. It seems to me like you're missing some data in top level query. What is `INF_F` supposed to point to?

Comment: There should be only parentheses around the subquery, i.e. only one pair of parentheses.

Comment: @ConsiderMe There are 3 tables we're working with here, STAGE_D, INT_F, and STAGE_LINK_B, i'm trying to make this SQL work so I can implement it somewhere else, like I said, i've never used connect by before, so some help with that is appreciated....what it's trying to accomplish is to loop through the ID_STAGE from STAGE_D where ID_STAGE = STAGE_LINK_B.ID_PRIOR_STAGE until STAGE_D.CD_STAGE = 'INT'

Comment: But there is no `INF_F` in `FROM` clause. You probably need a top level `SELECT`. This query seems to be missing some part.

Comment: ahhhh, i see what you're saying now

Answer (score 1):

I believe your immediate problem is `V$[STAGE_D.ID_STAGE]`.  It's not clear at all what that should be, syntactically.  I don't think square brackets are valid in any way here, and their presence is probably causing the parser to get confused and throw this not-very-clear error message.  I was able to reproduce the same error using similar syntax.

I don't know what to suggest you should change it to, because I really have no idea what the expression is meant to represent.  Usually "V$" in Oracle would be the beginning of a table or view name that contains dynamic information about internal database state (e.g. V$SESSION is a view that shows currently-connected database sessions).  But it seems clear that's not what you're looking for here.

Given that it is used in the `START WITH` clause, this is probably an expression that is meant to return some value that would be used to look up the first record.  But it is not meaningful in an Oracle context.  Perhaps the person who gave you this code is running it from some other context, where this expression is evaluated before passing the query to Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

It is an incomplete command.  If you boil it down to the basic components it works out to be:

```
( <Complex_table_definition> ) STG
WHERE <Conditions>
```

There is basically no `SELECT`, except as part of the definition of `STG`.

Comment: it tells me the error is "missing right parentheses" in line 7...i don't know what that V$... part is doing

Comment: The line numbers can be a little funny in my experience -- white space is removed first, and this can affect the line numbering; I wouldn't trust that "line 7" literally means the 7th line of code shown on screen.  I don't see why it is giving that specific error, but I did see a big problem that would cause *some* error.

Comment: Another thing: `START WITH` may need to come before `CONNECT BY`. Oracle may see it as a `CONNECT BY` with no `START WITH`, and then an "extra" `START WITH` as the start of a new clause without a closing parenthesis before it...